# How to split an iso and join them together?

Tags: iso

I have an ISO file about 24 GB. I want it to move to the other PC. My pendrive is about 16 GB. Is there any way I can part the iso and again join them together. This OC is ubuntu and other one is windows 7.

Comment: - Dont forget you also have alternatives: you also use the internet to upload and download the file. If the 2 systems are on the same network you can use ssh.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux/Ubuntu we have ...

```
SPLIT(1)                         User Commands                        SPLIT(1)

NAME
       split - split a file into pieces

SYNOPSIS
       split [OPTION]... [INPUT [PREFIX]]
```

You did not expect it to be that simple did you? How you join them again on Windows is not for AskUbuntu though. But you can also use `zipsplit`:

```
zipnote(1)                  General Commands Manual                 zipnote(1)

NAME
       zipsplit - split a zipfile into smaller zipfiles

SYNOPSIS
       zipsplit  [-t]  [-i]  [-p] [-s] [-n size] [-r room] [-b path] [-h] [-v]
       [-L] zipfile

ARGUMENTS
       zipfile  Zipfile to split.
```

I assume zip will be cross platform :)

Answer (score 0):

First solution in my mind was to mount the .iso for example by [FuriusIso](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/furiusisomount/). Then you can open the CD like every other folder and copy some part of files on your pendrive. It should appear in bookmarks in your files manager.